# Writing to object from parent component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'd like to have a list which maps the modified values back to the description in the container. In other way, I want the container to have a prop `shortcuts` like:

```
[{action: "foo"}]
```

with text being editable in the component created from the list.

I've got the container:

```
    Vue.component("shortcuts", {
      data: function () {
        return {
          shortcuts: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
        add: function() {
          this.shortcuts.push({
            action: "",
          })
        },
      },
      template: '<div>\
        <shortcut-entry v-for="(shortcut, index) in shortcuts" is="shortcut-entry" v-bind:key="index" v-bind="shortcut" @remove="shortcuts.splice(index, 1)"></shortcut-entry>\
        <br>\
        <button v-on:click=add>Add</button>\
        </div>'
    })
```

And the list element:

```
    Vue.component("shortcut-entry", {
      methods: {
        clearParams: function() {
          this.params = {}
        },
        remove: function() {
          this.$emit("remove")
        }
      },
      props: {
        action: String,
      },
      template: '<div>\
        <input type="text" v-model="action"></input>\
        <button v-on:click="remove">Remove</button>\
        </div>'
    })
```

However this results in a warning:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.

But if I use `data` instead of `props` in the `shortcut-entry`, the changes do not propagate into the objects in the list either.

What am I missing here? How can I bind the text entry in the item back to the object in the list in the container?

Comment: You should use the ``v-model`` or other modifiers (``.sync``) to update the parent's state.
Just remember do not push anything into the array, instead, make a new array.

Comment: Do not mutate the props passed to a component. Instead use an emit just like `remove` and pass a payload to the parent component, capture the payload in the parent component to identify which data item to be modified and do the modification in the parent component. the props should be modified in the parent component only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-model` to update the state:

```
Vue.component('shortcuts', {
  props: {
    value: Array // Of shortcuts
  },
  methods: {
    add: function () {
      const newValue = [...this.value, { action: '' }]
      this.$emit('input', newValue)
    },
    remove: function (index) {
      const newValue = [...this.value]
      newValue.splice(index, 1)
      this.$emit('input', newValue)
    }
  },
  template: '<div>\
  <shortcut-entry v-for="(shortcut, index) in value" is="shortcut-entry" v-bind:key="index" v-bind="shortcut" @remove="remove(index)"></shortcut-entry>\
  <br>\
  <button v-on:click=add>Add</button>\
  </div>'
```

And the parent component is something like this:

```
Vue.component('parent-comp', {
  data () {
    return {
      shortcuts: []
    }
  },
  template: '<shortcut v-model="shortcuts"></shortcut>'
})
```

*** Use .sync ***

```
Vue.component('shortcuts', {
  props: {
    shortcuts: Array // Of shortcuts
  },
  methods: {
    add: function () {
      const newValue = [...this.shortcuts, { action: '' }]
      this.$emit('update:shortcuts', newValue)
    },
    remove: function (index) {
      const newValue = [...this.shortcuts]
      newValue.splice(index, 1)
      this.$emit('update:shortcuts', newValue)
    }
  },
  template: '<div>\
  <shortcut-entry v-for="(shortcut, index) in shortcuts" is="shortcut-entry" v-bind:key="index" v-bind="shortcut" @remove="remove(index)"></shortcut-entry>\
  <br>\
  <button v-on:click=add>Add</button>\
  </div>'
})
```

So, the caller component:

```
Vue.component('parent-comp', {
  data () {
    return {
      shortcuts: []
    }
  },
  template: '<shortcut :shortcuts.sync="shortcuts"></shortcut>'
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the add/remove. I've got a followup question about the items themselves here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503140/dealing-with-many-attributes-mapping-to-a-parent-component-list-in-vuejs