# Dealing with many attributes mapping to a parent component list in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a list of components where I'd like them all to be editable / replicate state to the parent component.

The list component exists as:

```
Vue.component("shortcuts", {
  props: {
    shortcuts: Array
  },
  template: '...<shortcut-entry v-for="(shortcut, index) in shortcuts" v-bind:key="index" v-bind="shortcut" @remove="remove(index)"></shortcut-entry>...'
})
```

It's used with a model like this:

```
<shortcuts v-bind:shortcuts.sync="shortcuts"></shortcuts>
```

Now each `shortcut-entry` component will contain lots of values which I would like to be propagated back to the top level list of objects:

```
    Vue.component("shortcut-entry", {
      props: {
        mod_ctrl: Boolean,
        mod_alt: Boolean,
        mod_shift: Boolean,
        keypress: String,
        action: String,
        ...
      },
```

Each of those properties exists as a separate checkbox / input on the page with (for example) `<input ... v-model="action">`. The way I understand it, I could wire the update events back to the parent component and do replacements there... but that sounds like a lot of boilerplate code.

Can I somehow propagate any modifications for those props back to the parent component automatically? (avoiding the "Avoid mutating a prop directly" warning)

It seems to work as I expect if I move every prop I currently have into another level (so I have `props: {options: Object}`, v-bind it with `.sync` and assign everything there), but I'm looking into some more explicit solution which actually declares the relevant options ahead of time.

Comment: Hello, I was trying to formulate an anwser but it's hard. Am I right in concluding that there are basically two problems here 1) How can we let shortcut-entry propagete all known values back to the top level and 2) How can we avoid mutating prop in shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sync` modifier with the props object notation together. Instead of `v-bind="shortcut"` use `v-bind.sync="shortcut"`

This way `shortcut` component can declare all props (instead of just `options` object) and still be able to notify parent about mutation

But you need to change how you bind your inputs. Instead of `<input ... v-model="action">` you need to `<input ... v-bind:value="action" v-on:input="$emit('update:action', $event.target.value)">`. Problem with this is that different `<input>` types use [different names for value and change event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

To work around it and keep using `v-model` you can declare `computed` for each prop and use `v-model="actionComputed"`

```js
computed: {
  actionComputed: {
    get: function() { return this.action },
    set: function(value) { this.$emit('update:action', value) }
  }
}
```

So the result is again lot of boilerplate...

TL:DR

If you want all props declared ahead of time (instead of single prop of type `object`), some boilerplate is necessary. It can be reduced by generating `computed` props for `v-model` on the fly (same way [Vuex helpers](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace) generate `computed` to access and update Vuex state) but I don't think it is worth the effort. Just pass an object and let the `<input>` components mutate it's properties...